# Serving multiple Angular Universal apps in one Express app

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

I have two distinct Angular apps made with angular-cli, both already modified to run on a node.js server via Angular Universal following [Angular's tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering), but the example can only serve one app.

The example creates a view engine:

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Since each app has a different `index.html` file, I'd need to create two view engines, but how can I tell Express to use one engine in one route and another engine in another route?
In other words, how can I map `app1` to `/app1` and `app2` to `/app2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express application can mount multiple [sub-applications](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.onmount) to different endpoints:

```
const app1 = express();
const app2 = express();
...
app.use('/app1', app1);
app.use('/app2', app2);
app.listen(3000);
```

Sub-applications can have their own settings and shouldn't be `listen`ed.